# Bridging between Rosethal Inequalities and log convex tails

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent with $\mathbf{E}[X_i] = 0$ and $\mathbf{E}[|X_i|^t] < \infty$ for some $t \ge 2$. Write $\|X\|_p = (E|X|^p)^{1/p}$.

Then we have the classical "Rosenthal-type inequalities":
$$
\left\|\sum_i X_i \right\|_p
\le C_1\left(\sqrt{p}\left(\sum_i \|X_i\|_2^2\right)^{1/2} + p\left(\sum_i \|X_i\|_p^p\right)^{1/p}\right),
\\
\left\|\sum_i X_i \right\|_p
\le C_2\frac{p}{\log p}\left(\left(\sum_i \|X_i\|_2^2\right)^{1/2} + \left(\sum_i \|X_i\|_p^p\right)^{1/p}\right)
\\
\text{and in general}
\\
\left\|\sum_i X_i \right\|_p
\le C_3\min_{s=1}^p\left(\sqrt{s}e^{p/s}\left(\sum_i \|X_i\|_2^2\right)^{1/2} + s\left(\sum_i \|X_i\|_p^p\right)^{1/p}\right)
$$

On the other hand, if $X_i$ all have logarithmically concave tails; (that is, $\Pr[X \ge t = e^{−N(t)}]$
for $t \ge 0$, where $N : R_+ \to R_+ \cup\{\infty\}$ is a convex function), then we have the much stronger:

$$
\left\|\sum_i X_i \right\|_p
\le C_4\left(\sqrt{p}\left(\sum_i \|X_i\|_2^2\right)^{1/2} + \left(\sum_i \|X_i\|_p^p\right)^{1/p}\right).
$$
(Note there is no factor $p$ on the second term.)

Concave tails happen roughly as $\|X_i\|_p \sim p$, hence for random variables like this, we go from $p^2$ to just $p$.

**My question** is thus: Is there a series of results interpolating between the Rosenthal inequalities and the inequalities for heavy random variables?

It creates an odd "discontinuity" that the factor of $p$ disappears suddenly when the random variables get sufficiently heavy.

Interestingly, for identical random variables we can use the theorem
$$
\left\|\sum_i X_i \right\|_p
\le C_5 \sup_{\max\{2,p/n\}\le s\le p}\frac{p}{s}\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)^{1/s}\|X_1\|_s
$$
to show that $\|X\|_p \le p^c \implies \left\|\sum_i X_i \right\|_p \le C_6(\sqrt{pn} + (n/p)^{1/p}p^c)$ for any $c>0$, $p\le n$.
This can be interpreted as saying that the $p$-free version of the above inequalities is true in many cases, even when the random variables aren't that heavy.

(I should note that all results listed in this question can be found in Rafał Latała's: https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~rlatala/papers/AOPSUMS97.pdf)